# Copy everything happening on terminal to a text file

Tags: ubuntu, io, terminal

I am using the Ubuntu server 12.04. I run a simulator for GPGPU on the server.

I run a CUDA program on it by initializing the simulator and then run it by the command ./(exe_filename) in the corresponding directory.

There were many things happening on the terminal at a fast rate so that I was not able to see and understand what happening correctly.

So I wanna know whether there were anything like a command so that what is the text outputted on the terminal will be copied to a text file so that I can see it.

Sorry for my ignorance if it was a trivial thing........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe your output to **tee** by

```
./(exe_filename) | tee my_program.log
```

Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32070/how-to-write-terminal-contents-into-a-file).

Answer (score 0):

The simple way should be the built-in bash redirection to a file:

```
./(exe_filename) > exe_filename.log
```

This will redirect the output of `./(exe_filename)` to `exe_filename.log` file.

If you want also that the errors to be redirected to a file, you can use:

```
./(exe_filename) > exe_filename.log 2> exe_filename_errors.txt
```

See also: [All about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

Comment: Thank you very much and its working. Actually it is redirecting the things, is it also possible to give it both to the terminal and the log file